# funny type error in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm writing a program in C, which I am a complete beginner in, to find prime numbers. The problem I have is that when I initialize a variable to the int type like this...

```
int num;
```

and then stuff happens

```
blah blah blah
```

but nothing happens to num, it's kept in reserve and only used to modify other variables.

and then when I try

```
printf("%d",&num);
```

and compile it with gcc it gives me this error

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]
```

but it seems really silly, whats the difference between `int` and `int *`? and how can I print `num` if it isn't a `num`?
please help I'm so confused.

Answer (score 2):

`&` takes the address of `num`. Use

```
printf("%d\n",num);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it´s only a warning (a good one, but you can run the program nonetheless).
If you do that, you´ll see some strange number,
because you´re printing the memory address of your variable.
Remove the `&` to print the value (and to get rid of the warning too)

You´re probably thinking of scanf, there you need the &
(explanations at this point would be too long, wait until you´re familiar with pointers)

Answer (score 0):

Just to extrapolate a little bit... the difference between int and int* is that int* is a pointer to an int.  That means it doesn't actually hold an int value, it holds the address to an int value.